# FormValidation with Button State

Tags: reactjs

In my React app, I have a component call `<ComingSoonForm/>` Inside that, I have a TextInputField. If the Email valid, the Notify-Button is able. If the Email is invalid, the Notify-Button is disabled.

Here is my Component File:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TextInputField, toaster, Button, } from "evergreen-ui";
import Box from 'ui-box';
import { validateEmail } from "../FormValidation/FormValidator";

class ComingSoonForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      emailErr: {
        status: true,
        value: ""
      },
      email: "",
      isDisabled: true,
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.checkFormStatus = this.checkFormStatus.bind(this);
  }

  handleEmailInput = e => {
    const email = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ email: email});
    console.log(this.state.email);
    this.checkFormStatus();
  };

  handleSubmit() {
    if (this.checkFormStatus()) {
      alert("Form is OK")
    }
  }

  checkFormStatus() {
    // form validation middleware
    const { email } = this.state;
    const emailErr = validateEmail(email);

    if (!emailErr.status) {
      this.setState({isDisabled:false})
      return true;
    } else {
      this.setState({
        emailErr,
      });
      return false;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Box className="welcomePageWelcomeInnerLoginButton">
          <TextInputField
            marginTop={15}
            width={200}
            onChange={this.handleEmailInput}
            value={this.state.email}
            type="email"
            placeholder="Your email-address"
            inputHeight={40}
          />
        </Box>
        <Button height="40" appearance="primary" marginBottom={5} className="welcomePageWelcomeInnerLoginButtonWidth" disabled={this.state.isDisabled} onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Notify Me</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ComingSoonForm;
```

But this case doesn't work correctly. So when the command `console.log(this.state.email)` in the `handleEmailInput` Function run, I get the following data in the console:

I type one letter (t) and I get:

```
 //ComingSoonForm.js:25
```

I type a second letter (t) and I get:

```
t //ComingSoonForm.js:25
t //FormValidator.js:10
```

Why do I have to enter two letters in order for one to appear in the console?

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous. Make a search and you'll find tons of info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setState is asynchronous, you can pass a callback method as a second parameter like this:

```
handleEmailInput = e => {
  const email = e.target.value;
  this.setState({ email: email }, () => console.log(this.state.email));
  this.checkFormStatus();
};
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer, it works now and good luck on stackoverflow as new contributor ;)